# compare two columns values in two different pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have two data sets; set A has the full values with columns' names ('Temp', 'Humidity', 'Label' ) and set B has predictions for the Label value for some of the readings of the full list ('Temp', 'Humidity', 'Predicted Label'). I want to compare the Label value of the same readings in both full lists and the predictions to calculate the error. How can I do that using pandas?

Comment: Please provide sample data and code of the solution that you have tried. And also it'd be better if you can provide sample output of what you are expecting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge your two Dataframes.
What do you mean by comparing? Are those numbers? If so you can do this :

```
Comparison_Dataframe = A.merge(B, on=['Temp', 'Humidity'], how='inner')
Comparison_Dataframe['result'] = Comparison_Dataframe['Label'== 'Predicted Label']
```

The second line would add a boolean equality column.

Answer (score 0):

If by error you mean difference, and both dataframes are ordered the same:

```
df = A - B
```